# VSTO Outlook: How to uniquely identify custom task panes and remove the appropriate one from Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes collection

Tags: outlook, vsto, interop, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have an VSTO Outlook Add-in. I have created a custom task pane that is always visible in all the windows at the top, explorer and inspector windows (compose window, etc.). This task pane is always the same, I mean, it has the same title/name, and also it embeds the exactly same user control.

Now I am facing a particular scenario and it is the following: When I open the inspector window (well the compose window), a new custom task pane which is always the same as the one in the explorer window, is added to the top of the compose window. Then when I close compose window I want to remove the custom task pane associated to this inspector (compose window), because otherwise where returning to the explorer window I get more than one custom task panes visible. So I am not able to detect which is the right task pane associated to the inspector opened in order to remove it from Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes using RemoveAt method. The problem I see is that it looks like every task pane added to the Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes collection is indentified through its name and the control that it embeds, but what happens when you have more than one task pane added to that collection with the same name/title and user control? There's no way to uniquely identify each of them.

I have a wrapper for inspector window, so I thought of handle the inspector open and close events and in the open event handler get the index of the custom task pane added to the Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes and then use that index to remove the correponding pane in the inspector close event.

Is this the correct way to do it? or is there any other better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into similar confusion while working on a Word addin.  Office handles Word & Outlook customtaskpanes differently, so my solution won't map exactly to yours, but I do have a few suggestions:

Check out [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/custom-task-panes?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp#Outlook) section from official MS documentation:

- To associate the task pane with a specific Explorer or Inspector, use the *CustomTaskPaneCollection.Add* method to create the task pane, and pass the Explorer or Inspector object to the *window* parameter.

I found the method signature you'll need [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.customtaskpanecollection.add?view=vsto-2017):

**Add(UserControl, String, Object)**

- Creates a new CustomTaskPane and adds it to the current CustomTaskPaneCollection. The custom task pane is based on the specified UserControl, has the specified title, and is associated with the specified application window.

So to answer your question, MS seems to think this is the "correct" way to do it.

In my opinion, adding a field or property via a wrapper class makes perfect sense too.  Especially if you already have it implemented & working properly.

Other suggestions based on my experience wrangling customtaskpanes:

- Add an instance field/property to your usercontrol, obviating the need to wrap the customtaskpane class.
- Create static class-level lists like *List<< customtaskpane >> inspectorPanes* in situations where you need to group or track them.

Hope this helps,